# Two different outputs form QGIS basic statistics

Tags: qgis, statistics

I have two separate line layers, each with a `length` attribute column.  When I compute basic statistics on the first layer's column, it works as expected, producing `Mean`, `StdDev`, and so on

[image]:

But when I input the second layer's length column, I get a different result:
[image]

**Both** columns are in real number, length 20, precision 2 format. There are no null values.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Are both line layers have same projection? Please check.

Comment: Yes they are in the same projection.

Comment: How are you getting this basic statistics output? The only basic stats I can get from my qgis 2.18 is via Vector... Analysis Tools... Basic stats for numeric fields.. but the output dialog looks nothing like that. Is this from another plugin, and what version of qgis is it?

Comment: Did you use "Show Statistical Summary"? In 2.18 the window is different here. Did you try Statis plug-in?

Comment: Can you share your shapefiles so that others could test what the problem could be?